# Any cons in using Portals instead of passing components as props?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we have a `SidebarLayout` component which renders the following HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-layout">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

To add sidebar content I can easily pass another component as a prop such as:

```
<SidebarLayout sidebarContent={() => (<SomeOtherComponent />)}>
    ...
</SidebarLayout>
```

and then have a `render` function for the `SidebarLayout` as:

```
class SidebarLayout extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
        const { sidebarContent: SidebarContent } = this.props;

        return (
            <div id="sidebar-layout">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    {SidebarContent &&
                        <SidebarContent />
                    }
                </div>
                <div id="content" />
            </div>
        )
   }
}
```

This is how we had it working so far. However, React 16 introduced Portals which allow us to render component outside their original React tree and typical examples are usually given as modals, popovers etc.

Portals also made it possible to use them to position elements inside their own parents as well. This means it's possible to achieve exactly the same result as above with the following code (less important code is omitted):

```
class SidebarLayout extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="sidebar-layout">
                <div id="sidebar" />
                <div id="content" />
            </div>
        )
   }
}
```

```
class SidebarContentPortal extends React.Component {
    portalId = "sidebar";

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.el = document.createElement("div");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const contentBar = document.getElementById(this.portalId);

        contentBar.appendChild(this.el);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        const contentBar = document.getElementById(this.portalId);

        contentBar.removeChild(this.el);
    }

    render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            this.props.children,
            this.el
        );
    }
}
```

Now we use the `SidebarContentPortal` as:

```
<SidebarLayout>
    ...
    <SidebarContentPortal>
        ...
    </SidebarContentPortal>
</SidebarLayout>
```

I'm wondering if there is any drawbacks or cons in using portals in this exact way as opposed to passing components as props which we're used to before Portals were introduced?

Comment: Portals are useful if <div id="sidebar-layout"> is provided as static HTML, they don't make sense if you render it with React. Accessing DOM directly is a drawback itself. Don't do this if you don't really have to. It's incompatible with SSR and doesn't play well with isolated unit tests, for starters.